# I am trying to install OpenSS and a LAMP server

Tags: 14.04, grub2, software-installation, lamp

The process goes through all the way to the [GRUB 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#GRUB_version_2_.28GRUB.29) installer and then fails on `/dev/sda`. I have two hard drives, one 250 GB and the other 200 GB and am running 4 GB [DDR2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM) [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory).

The computer did have a Windows 7 system on it, but I removed it as it kept crashing and rebooting.

I wiped the drivers using [DBAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darik%27s_Boot_and_Nuke) as it has failed on the GRUB 2 install.

DBAN is currently finishing, so I will try again after it has run its course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run a disk check on the drives?  Sounds like a bad sector causing the crashing.  Get the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) and run some diagnostics.

Comment: sorry yes i believe it open SSL. what is the difference or is there not one, thankyou will try the boot cd